# Windows Vista Sidebar Equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sidebar

I'm trying to create an application that looks similar to the Windows Vista sidebar. There's an API that allows docking toolbars on the screen (AppBar), but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

How can I attach a Form to the desktop and dock it to the side of the screen, but without preventing other windows from overlapping it?

Comment: This requires continously checking to make sure the windows is in the foreground.

Comment: Just change the properties for the Window. TopMost, CanResize, and set it to windowless. Then you can just change the position of the window to the most right of the screen and the height of the screen, take in account the taskbar and you're set.

Comment: Shouldn't be there any solution to use AppBar for docking, but without overlapping prevention?

Comment: What about [autohiding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#autohide_application_desktop_toolbars) an appbar? That also solves the Window's sidebar's problem of needing a shortcut key to summon it back when it's covered by other windows.

Answer (score 1):

With all the following options you get a Sidebar look-a-like (the code below is for a WPF Window):

```
//width of the sidebar
Width = 300;
//height (remember to add a reference to the System.Windows.Forms dll)
Height = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
//no window style means no border
WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
//not resizable
ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
//allow a transparent sidebar
AllowsTransparency = true;
//change the color
Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.CadetBlue);
//set the opacity (how much transparent)
Opacity = 0.5d;
//offset from the top
Top = 0;
//offset from the left (calculated so it shows on the right side)
Left = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - (double)GetValue(WidthProperty);
//set it the topmost window
Topmost = true;
//hide the icon from the taskbar
ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

Hope this helps!

**Update:**

Here's a similar solution for when you're using WindowsForms, altough with WPF you have much more possibilities! The differences are minor, everything explains itself. The last line I added hides the window taskbar-icon. Do not place the code in the constructor of the Form but in the Load-event, otherwise the Location will be wrong. In WPF this doesn't matter.

```
Width = 300;
Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
BackColor = Color.CadetBlue;
Opacity = 0.5d;
Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Width, 0);
TopMost = true;
ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

Comment: Windows Form doesn't have a Background property. This sounds like WPF. Also, the code appears to be inconsistent.

Comment: Can I ask what's stopping you from using WPF than WinForms?

Comment: See my updated answer for a WinForms solution. @SandeepBansal: I was wondering the same! :D