# Center image vertical and horizontal in a universal app (xaml/wpf)

Tags: wpf, xaml, win-universal-app

I tried to use a grid (inside a grid)

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#2f1807" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="71"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="505"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Source="Assets/logo.png" Height="71" Width="505" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Stretch="None" />
</Grid>
```

The image has a height of 71 pixels and width of 505 pixels. and this is the output:
[image]
So the horizontal center worked, but no vertical and the image width should fill up the whole cell. Why is this not working?

the output of `uniform`:

[image]

image prop (sorry for the dutch language) size is 505 width and 71 px height.

[image]

**edit as @YoupTube suggests:**

```
<Image 
    Source="Assets/logo.png" 
    Height="71" 
    Width="505" 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Grid.Row="0" 
    MinWidth="505" 
    MinHeight="71" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the outer grid row definitions as well please? looks like something else is causing the layout issues for this grid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you have restricted the `Height` of the `Grid` so that it is the same size as the `Image`. The solution is to remove the `Height` setting on the `RowDefinition` (or remove the whole `RowDefinition`) and let the `Grid` fill the space of its parent container... *then* the `Image` can be centred vertically:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#2f1807" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="505"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Source="Assets/logo.png" Height="71" Width="505" Grid.Column="1" 
        Grid.Row="0" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

In order for your `Image` to be centred vertically, it *must* be in a container that has a larger `Height` value than the `Image`. I see that your `Grid` is in another `Grid`... if the `Image` takes the whole `Height` of this `Grid`, then you must put this `Grid` into a container that has more `Height` than this `Grid` and centre that instead:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#2f1807" 
    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" MinHeight="150">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="505"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Source="Assets/logo.png" Height="71" Width="505" Grid.Column="1" 
        Grid.Row="0" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: adding the `horizontalalignment="center"` and removing the rowdef gives me: http://i.imgur.com/pE1jeQK.png can it relate to me using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826568/creating-a-sidebar-flyout-like-windows-desktop-app-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you just have to set:

```
<Image VerticalAlignment="Center" ... />
```

Comment: I have updated the question with your suggestion. though thanks for your time and effort! :)